# Primeng Datatable 4.3: array changes not populated

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

**I'm using primeng 4.3**

I've coded this primeng datatable:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="quotes" [editable]="true">
  <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field 
    [header]="col.header" [editable]="col.editable">
    <ng-template let-col let-quote="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
      <p-spinner size="30" [(ngModel)]="quote[col.field]" name="quote"</p-spinner>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

The problem appears when `this.quotes` changes. I mean, when a new array is populated on `this.quotes`, datatable doesn't populates changes.

In order to make sure a new array is populated I'm using:

```
this.quotes = Object.assign([], calculatedQuotes);
```

So, I mean, each time `this.quotes` is assigned, it has a new reference to a new array.

Any ideas?

**I'm using primeng 4.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As PRIMENG doc says:](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table)

> Change Detection Table may need to be aware of changes in its value in
>   some cases such as reapplying sort. For the sake of performance, this
>   is only done when the reference of the value changes meaning a setter
>   is used instead of ngDoCheck/IterableDiffers which can reduce
>   performance. So when you manipulate the value such as removing or
>   adding an item, instead of using array methods such as push, splice
>   create a new array reference using **a spread operator or similar**.

So your ways is correct to see changes in your table:

```
this.quotes = Object.assign([], calculatedQuotes);
```

To add new item to your grid, you can use spread operator:

```
this.quotes = [...this.quotes , newObject];
```

Comment: I've not specified any `ChangeDetectionStrategy`. As far I've been able to figure out, I'm already changing reference (`Object.assign([],...`). If references changes it should be populated, shouldn't? I've also tried to use `ChangeDetectorRef`, but I'm getting an `providerData is undefined`...

Comment: @Jordi please, see my updated answer. I've read more thoroughly docs of primeng table. Now it is clear why it happens.